# Call ExtJS functions from action script

Tags: javascript, flash, extjs, actionscript

I wonder if it is possible to call ExtJS functions from the action script?
For example we have the following code written on ExtJS:

```
Ext.define('utils', {
    singleton : true,
    alert : function (message) {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert(Ext.locale.error, message);
    }
});
```

Can it be called from within action script? I know that plain java script function can be called using `ExternalInterface()`, but it's not suitable for me.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why is external interface not suitable for you? External interface is the standard method for communicating between ActionScript and JavaScript.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet, to be honest I do not know how to call Extjs function using `ExternalInterface()`. Do you have any example? As I said, it's pretty straightforward to call plain JS function, but I don't understand how to call extjs one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the ExternalInterface method in detail but using Ext.define you simply define a javascript object (as it is a singleton) with your given method. So in javascript you could simply call

```
utils.alert('Hello World');
```

So shouldn't it be possible to use the following simple call

```
ExternalInterface.call('utils.alert', 'Hello World');
```

Comment: Huh, that works. My fault that I don't try the easiest way. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Extjs, but the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.app.Application) states that the `Application` class sets up a global variable with the name of your app. If you add a public method to that class you should be able to call it from Flash using `ExternalInterface` (see [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)), which is the standard method of communicating between Flash and JavaScript.

**Extjs:**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            items: {
                html: 'My App'
            }
        });
    },
    // Public method to receive external interface calls from Flash
    alert: function(message) {
        // Call alert method on utils
    }
});
```

**ActionScript:**

```
ExternalInterface.call('myApp.alert', 'Hello JavaScript. Love from Flash');
```

Comment: Application sets up the global variable, but that's not the case I have. However, in my case (using define instead of application), such an approach works as well.